# Create discount rule to give rounded discount

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

We are a mail order fashion retailer and often send catalogues with rounded discount prices. I want to create a shopping basket rule which gives rounded discount. For eg. style A costs £199 and discount is 25%. Now instead of final price £149.25, I want £149 at the checkout (and not just truncate/hide the decimals but actually charge £149 to customer).

Comment: For Style A in your example, you could use a £50 off rule, instead of 25% off. Would this work?

Comment: Thanks Wes. I should have included more in details. I have 150 styles (at diff prices) and 50 different promotion codes (each giving 25% off). So all these 50 styles should give rounded discount for Style A. But this will lead to creating 7500 codes (50 codes for 150 styles)